# Incorrect URL encoding in permalinks

Tags: php, wordpress, url, url-rewriting, permalinks

I am having a problem with the way wordpress is encoding the urls provided by `<?php echo the_permalink() ?>`

The permalink setting are set to year/month/post-title and the permalinks look just like they should in the post editor.

Two things are happening.  Some of the permalinks are being encoded with %20 instead of dashes and some are just getting spaces.  The really tricky part is that some of the links work and some throw an error.

For example, a link that looks like this: /link to page  - and another that looks like this: /link%20to%20page  - both point to the same page, both are being served out of the same function, one of them works and one does not.

Any help, or even just any ideas, would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not really sure the if the issue is where you think it is - there shouldn't be any Wordpress pages with whitespace in the permalink as it converts them to dashes when you save the page?  FYI you don't need to `echo` - the function already prints, if you want to return the value use `get_permalink` - but this shouldn't be related to the issue.

Comment: I appreciate the response, but that's actually the most confusing thing about this.  The permalinks in the editor are correct.So if I have a page named "First Example Page" the permalink in the editor is first-example-page.  The permalinks are working, they just aren't displaying properly.  I didn't build this site, I took it over, right now I'm searching the code for something the original developer may have done to change the way the permalinks are output.

Comment: I've never come across this and without being able see, let alone tinker with some code I'm sorry to say my suggestions will read along the lines of "have you tried switching it on and off?".  It could be anything.  Possibly a filter that's been erroneously added (or removed).  Have you tried disabling plugins (one at a time)?  How does the URL read when you view the HTML-source?  IE. at least then you can determine either client/server side problem. (it could easily be a Javascript that's screwing with the link after the page has loaded). Can you post a link to the site?